Solving ODE system with less equations
In sensitivity analysis, there is a set of equations called sensitivity equations. They're obtained by differentiating your initial IVP with respect to the parameters. For example:
If your IVP is:
$\ddot{z}+C\dot{z}+Kz=0$, $z(0)=2, \dot{z}(0)=-C$
With $K,C$ being your parameters, then you differentiate with respect to $K$ and $C$ to obtain:
$\frac{d^2z_{K}}{dt^2}+C\frac{dz_{K}}{dt}+z+Kz_K=0,z_K(0)=0,\frac{dz_{K}}{dt}(0)=0$
$\frac{d^2z_{C}}{dt^2}+\dot{z}+C\frac{dz_{C}}{dt}+Kz_C=0,z_C(0)=0,\frac{dz_{C}}{dt}(0)=-1$
Where $z_C=\frac{\partial z}{\partial C}, z_K=\frac{\partial z}{\partial K}$
My question is, can you solve the two equation system (for $z_C$
and $z_K$
) without solving the original equation?
The problem is that, if you solved the first equation while trying to solve the system, it makes no sense to differentiate the equation; you could just find what $z$ is and then calculate  $\frac{\partial z}{\partial C}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial K}$.
The book I'm reading induces that this is possible, but I'm suspicious it isn't.
Thank you for the help!

@EricTowers Yes, makes more sense. I've edited it, thanks!

Yes, in this case of a linear equation you do not need to solve the original equation as prerequisite to solve the sensitivity equations.
This is of course different for non-linear equations, as each non-linear term will have an inner derivative under the derivation for the parameters, and this inner derivative still depends on the original solution. So if $\dot y=f(y;K)$, $y(0)=y_0(C)$, the, you get in the partial derivatives
$$
\dot y_K=\partial_yf(y;K)y_K+\partial_Kf(y;K),~~y_K(0)=0\\
\dot y_C=\partial_yf(y;K)y_C,~~y_C(0)=\partial_Cy_0(C)\\
$$
As the remaining partial derivatives are not constant, you need the solution $y$ to evaluate them.
